# how to fix setTimeout gets faster after new tab

Tags: javascript, settimeout

i have a question.

I want to make an animation that changes the background images while using the TweenMax slide.
It works, however open a new browser tab and see that it slows down or faster code when you come back.
I think it's a matter of setTimeout and tweenmax repeat-1.

Here is code.
Can tweenmax be executed within a function?
please help me.

```js
var rollImg = ["https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/fire-letter-a-of-burning-flame-picture-id844027508?k=6&m=844027508&s=170667a&w=0&h=dt0qXfyejRq_kjs5PqXcMf7Fij_opW7w1kfhfmH6dyQ=",
"https://cdn.leroymerlin.com.br/products/letra_b_11cm_acrilico_preto_kami_acrilicos_89622526_0001_600x600.jpg"];

var layer1Interval = 4000;
var layer2Interval = 5000;
var animationInterval = 1000;
$(function() {
  var roll = 1;
  function rollFnc () {
    setTimeout(function() {
      roll++;
      if (roll > 2) {
        roll = 1;
      }
      $("#box1").attr("src", rollImg[roll - 1]);
      setTimeout(rollFnc, layer1Interval + animationInterval * 1.5);
    }, animationInterval / 2);
  }
  
  rollFnc();
})

var tl = new TimelineMax({

  repeatDelay: (layer1Interval / 1000)
});
tl.from(".layer1", animationInterval / 1000, {
  scaleX: 0,
  transformOrigin: "left",
  ease: 'expo.inOut'
});
tl.to(".layer1", animationInterval / 1000, {
  scaleX: 0,
  transformOrigin: "right",
  ease: 'expo.out'
});
```

```css
,
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  width: 40.4%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.7%;
  left: 15%;
}

.box1 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.box2 {
  width: 19.9%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.7%;
  left: 56.8%;
}

.box2 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.layer1 {
  background-color: #f85983;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.layer2 {
  background-color: #f85983;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.0.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="box1">
      <div class="layer1" id="layer1"></div>
      <img id="box1" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/fire-letter-a-of-burning-flame-picture-id844027508?k=6&m=844027508&s=170667a&w=0&h=dt0qXfyejRq_kjs5PqXcMf7Fij_opW7w1kfhfmH6dyQ=" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Consider using setInterval (once!) instead of calling a function on timeout, *that then sets a new timeout*..

Comment: I'd say the issue is that `rollFunc` sets **two** timers, the latter recursively calling `rollFunc` which sets two more, ad infinitum

Comment: @Phil - that's a much better way of putting it. :thumbs-up:

Comment: thanks for comment! sorry, i don't understand... please could you show me.... a code sample

Comment: Since you're doing animations, consider using [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead.